# Difference between `.GlobalEnv` and `globalenv()`

Tags: r

What is the difference? I read [Hadley](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Environments.html) but this is not clear to me.
Furthermore, should I call it as `envir=...` or `env=...`? It seems it doesn't make a difference.
For examples see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4837477/remove-objects-in-globalenv-from-within-a-function) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9726705/assign-multiple-objects-to-globalenv-from-within-a-function).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`.GlobalEnv` is a symbol to which the global environment is bound. `globalenv` is a function which returns the global environment. In practice, you can use both, although the former is faster by some nano-seconds.

Regarding your second question, study the language definition regarding [argument matching](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-lang.html#Argument-matching), in particular, partial name matching.